# Catching Perforce polling failures in Jenkins with Text Finder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

Our Perforce server goes down too much, and we get email notifications for each failure, like:

```
P4: Unable to connect: com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException: The filesystem 'P4LOG' has only 127.94M free, but the server configuration requires at least 250M available.

P4: Connection retry: 1
P4: Connection retry giving up...
P4: Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException
P4: Unable to close Perforce connection.
```

Or, like:

```
P4: Unable to connect: com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException: Unable to connect to Perforce server at myp4:1666
P4: Connection retry: 1
P4: Connection retry giving up...

P4 Task: establishing connection.
P4: Server connection error: myp4:1666

P4 Task: Unable to connect.
ERROR: 
P4 Task: Unable to connect.
```

I'm using the Text Finder plugin to search the console.  If the pattern is found, I want the build marked as unstable.  (I don't want all of our users spammed just because a server went down temporarily.)  My regex is:

```
(ConnectionException: Unable to connect to Perforce server|Unable to setup workspace: java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

I've also checked "Unstable if found" and "Also search the console output".

The plugin appears to work because I find this entry in the build log:

```
[PostBuildScript] - Execution post build scripts.
...
Archiving artifacts
Checking console output
/data/home/jenkins/jobs/packages/jobs/myjob/jobs/myjob__main/builds/12079/log:
P4: Unable to connect: com.perforce.p4java.exception.ConnectionException: Unable to connect to 
Perforce server at myp4:1666
...
Finished: FAILURE
```

Why is Text Finder failing to mark the job as unstable, even though it found the required pattern?

BTW, this job has 2 input sources.  It uses the Perforce poller, but it also has a periodic timer, so it can catch changes in a second source.

Thanks!